# Python scipy optimize calibration of two simultaneous function

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, calibration, scipy-optimize-minimize

...... I've used python scipy optimize to solve; which is my go-to replacement for the equivalent of Excel solver.
Right now, stumped, as somehow I cannot get my python code to work using two simultaneous equation.
Fundamentally, my situation is

1. I have a function, volatility_ = function(x1, x2, x3..., strike).
2. I have another function, delta_ = function(x1, x2, x3, ...., strike, volatility_)

Now, my goal is to find the value of volatility, given a specific delta (such as 0.25). As above, this value of volatility can be found using a (numpy) defined polynomial function under volatility_.

I thought the 'calibration' way is to use a solver-type (newton-raphson etc) such that we find the condition where delta_target - delta_loop = 0.0.
Below is my python code, which I can't seem to get it to work.

```
### test function for implied delta strike volatility using iterative search
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import minimize    

vol_data = np.array([0.64809911, 0.63919358, 0.63206613, 0.62659096, 0.62264224,
   0.62009416, 0.6188209 , 0.61869664, 0.61959558, 0.62139189,
   0.62717338, 0.63090691, 0.65296991, 0.66915861])
strike_data = np.array([1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2400,
   2500, 3000, 3500])

def vol_fit(r_ = 0.0, S_ = 1.0, T_ = 1.0, strike_ = np.array([]), vols_ = np.array([]), delta_target = 0.25):
    
    def delta_calc(r, S, K, T, sigma, type_):
        d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + sigma**2/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
        try:
            if type_ == "c":
                delta_calc = stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
            elif type_ == "p":
                delta_calc = -stats.norm.cdf(-d1, 0, 1)
            return delta_calc
        except:
            print("Please confirm option type, either 'c' for Call or 'p' for Put!")
    
    # we initialize the curve-fit of strike and vols under the local-volatility model
    coeff_ = np.polyfit(strike_, vols_, 3)
    
    # lets use numpy poly eval co-efficients instead
    def vol_local(coeff_, strike_):
        """Function 2, this is the implied volatility using local-vol"""
        # return y1 * (strike**3) + y2 * (strike**2) + y3 * (strike**1) + y4
        return np.polyval(coeff_, strike_)
    
    def calib_(x):
        sigma_ = vol_local(coeff_, strike_)
        delta_implied = delta_calc(r = r_, S = S_, K = x[0], T = T_, sigma = sigma_, type_ ='c')
     
        return delta_implied - delta_target # delta target is 0.25, for example
    
    x0 = np.array([S_]) # initial guess for alpha, rho, volvol
    bounds = [(0.1 * S_, None)]
    res = minimize(calib_, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds)
    result_ = res.x
    
    return np.polyval(coeff_, result_)
    
vol_fit(r_ = 0.0, S_ = 1700, T_ = 1.0, strike_ = strike_data,\
        vols_ = vol_data, delta_target = 0.25)
```

The error I am getting is below

```
The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value.
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the indentation, I am unable to run your script. Also, the `def vol_fit(r_ = 0.0, S_ = 1.0, T_ = 1.0, strike_ = np.array([]), vols_ = np.array([]), delta_target = 0.25): ` does not make sense, it is just the function signature. kindly double check the reproducibility

Comment: @lifezbeautiful, edited the python code. It should just 'run' with the reproducible error now.

Thanks for the flag.

Comment: The error means what the error says. Your objective function returns a vector when it needs to return a scalar. `vol_local` returns a vector. `sigma` is a vector. `delta_calc` is a vector. You need to decide where this is collapsed to a scalar cost to minimize.